# How to configure HTTPS using Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, https

I am trying to configure Tomcat to listen to port 443 for HTTPS, but it does not work. I get no log in the `localhost_access_log.*.txt` file and no error in `catalina.out`.

This is my `server.xml` file:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443" />
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="/home/iis/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" />
```

How do I solve the problem or where can I find more information?

I generate my keystore with this command:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

Comment: Why `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol`?

Comment: @Andremoniy it was initially there. what should be there instead?

Comment: Ports below 1024 require root privileges in Linux, but that's probably not the problem if port 80 is working for you.

Comment: 'Does not work' is not a problem description. What happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

first configure a keystore

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

reflect in server.xml

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
  -keystore \path\to\my\keystore
```

then add connector to your server.xml file

```
<!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the keystore password, which you had forgotten to set that in `server.xml` file. You must change `keystorePass="changeit"` to `keystorePass="YOUR_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"` in https `Connector` element in `server.xml`

Comment: How do you know the password isn't 'changeit'?

Comment: because I am the author of this question and in documentations I found, it was not clear that i must write keystore password there! they said that place that line in Connector and then change the address of  to the keystore! and I thought it is a configuration! I wrote this answer to help others if stick in this situation